# How can I resize the FacetFilterItems length?

Tags: javascript, css, xml, sapui5

I couldn't manage to resize FacetFilterItem of FacetFilter. Here an image how it looks now.[image: FacetFilterItem Length]

and my code :

```
<m:FacetFilter
    id="idFacetFilter"
    type="Simple"
    showPersonalization="false"
    showReset="true"
    reset="onFacetFilterReset" 
    showPopoverOKButton="true">

    <m:lists>

        <m:FacetFilterList 
            title="{...}"
            key="{...}"
            multiselect="true"                  
            listClose="onFacetClosed"
            items="{...}" >

            <m:items>
                <m:FacetFilterItem
                    key="{...}"
                    text="{...}" />
            </m:items>
        </m:FacetFilterList>....
```

I want it's looks to be equal with the longest word in facet. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of the [`sap.m.FacetFilter`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/FacetFilter.js) contains a `sap.m.Popover` which is assigned with a contentWidth of 30%. So the Popover will take 30% of the available width by default.

I think there is (not yet) a property to change this. However, you can change this by overwriting some CSS classes. Keep in mind that overwriting them might have some side effects to other controls in your application so you should box them.

Here´s a simple [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jajaruvola/edit?css,js,output) to test it.